Python static property autocomplete list not working in PyCharm
I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 2024.2.4.  Autocomplete function lists appear correctly except in the case where I have a static property returning an object instance.
The static property syntax comes from this post: @staticmethod with @property
class staticproperty(property):
  def __get__(self, owner_self, owner_cls):
    return self.fget()

class _ScorecardClass(object):
    _average = 0

    @property
    def average_score(self) -> float:
        return self._average

    @average_score.setter
    def average_score(self, value):
        self._average = value

class MainClass(object):

    @staticmethod
    def _get_scorecard():
        return _ExternalDataProvider._get_scorecard()

    @staticproperty
    def Scorecard() -> _ScorecardClass:
        r"""Returns the scorecard."""
        return MainClass._get_scorecard()

In calling code, I can access the Scorecard object via its static property as follows:
MainClass.ScoreCard

However, the average_score property is not shown in the popup function list for ScoreCard.  If I enter the function name manually, the code runs correctly.
average = MainClass.ScoreCard.average_score

I have the various code-completion options enabled in PyCharm. It seems to work fine for instance properties, but not statics. The auto-complete list displays correctly in VS Code. I have tried Python 3.9 and 3.12 and it's the same in both cases.
If I do:
sc: _ScorecardClass

The sc variable shows the various properties of _ScorecardClass in its autocomplete list, complete with docstring when the property is highlighted.

This isn't the first time shoddy Python tooling has burnt us before a release. Just found Numpy-style docstrings are also broken in PyCharm/Python 3.12. Unfortunately we can't ditch PyCharm because many of our users depend on it. The question above is mainly to see if I've missed a trick in Python/if there's another way of achieving the same when the class is used statically, that also works around the autocomplete issue.
